# Is the derivative of a Lipschitz function square integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functional-analysis

Let $f(x)$  be a Lipschitz  real-valued function defined on a closed interval $I$. The derivative $f '(x)$ exists a.e. since $f$ is absolutely continuous.

My question is: Is $f '(x)$ necessarily square integrable, i.e. in $L^2(I)$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because the derivative is bounded.  If $M$ is the Lipschitz constant, then $|f'(x)|\leq M$ everywhere it exists.  This follows from the fact that each of the difference quotients has this bound.  Lipschitz continuous functions on $I$ are precisely the indefinite integrals of bounded measurable functions on $I$, whereas AC functions are the indefinite integrals of integrable functions on $I$.  (Thus you find AC counterexamples to this by integrating integrable but not square integrable functions.)