# Prove $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Following this question:[$f$ is integrable, prove $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$ is uniformly continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145222/f-is-integrable-prove-fx-int-inftyx-ft-dt-is-uniformly-continuo)

Our question is that let $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$. Prove $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$ is uniformly continuous.

---

I have the following Lemma:

> If for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\mu(A)=\mu([\min\{x, y\}, \max\{x,y\}])<\delta$, then
> $$
> \int_{A}|f|<\epsilon.
> $$

Can we use this Lemma to prove our result? Since for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ so that
$$
|F(x)-F(y)|\le \int_{A}|f|<\epsilon
$$
whenever $\mu(A)<\delta$ and $A=[\min\{x, y\}, \max\{x,y\}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here, $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, so $\mu (\{min \{x,y\}, \max \{x,y\})=|y-x|$ and the Lemma can be directly applied.